# Free Online/Offline information security courses/trainings with certification

Tags: untagged

Is there any websites provide free Online/Offline information security courses/trainings with certification ?

Comment: And if you get such certification will you provide your professional services for free?

Comment: @John Gardeniers, Companies offering preference to who have certificate. Poor students and who all working as a admin in small company can't earn these certifications.So i asked this. If my question is wrong, sorry. And i can't provide my professional service as free. But if i earn more, I'll provide like this service to students free who all willing to learn for secure their network.

Comment: You can provide your professional services for free. It's how a lot of folks gain experience. However, they usually choose to work for charities and the like. Say you donate your time and experience to a local Red Cross chapter (since I know that's an international charity) or a local school looking to get new computers setup and configured securely. That will count on the experience side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free study guides and the like? Absolutely. Free certification? No. At least none that would be recognized by hiring folks and security folks. Some certifications to consider (all of which you must pay to take an exam and in some cases must meet security requirements):

- ISC2 Certified Systems Security Certified Practioner (SSCP)
- ISC2 Certified Information Systems Security Professional (CISSP)
- CompTIA Security+
- ISACA Certified Information Systems Auditor (CISA)
- ISACA Certified Information Systems Manager (CISM)
- EC-Council Certified Ethical Hacker (CEH)
- Cisco Certified Security Professional (CCSP)
- The GSEC series of certifications